# How to read name of html helper element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

Is there in mvc any opportunity to read a name which will be assigned to html control?

For example I use this code:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

    <div>
        I want to display here a TextBox name
    </div>

</div>
```

And I want to get a name of input name. This code is fragment of partial view.
Name of element looks like *children[1].Name*

Comment: What would be the use of it? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Name") 
Or you can use extension method for generic HtmlHelper to use this with Lambda Expressions

```
public static string GetFullHtmlFieldName<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    return htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
}
```

The use would be `(Html.GetFullHtmlFieldName(x => x.Name)`

Comment: @archil I cannot use lambda expression for variable. there are no overloads for that. only string type is supplied.

Comment: You can use @Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Name")

Comment: @tugberk_ugurlu: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Yes you must use @Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Name").

Comment: @Hallaghan MVC 3 with razor view engine. lambada is not supported. I am very curious how you two accomplish that :s yours is MVC 3 as fas as I understood?

Comment: @user677202 then, what is the point of using that. just write the name as plain text on the cshtml page:)

Comment: Point is that TemplateInfo has the Property HtmlFieldPrefix that is prepended to field names and ids. It may be set by Render() caller, outside the view. GetFullHtmlFieldName() method uses this field automatically

Comment: @archil my question is that : it only excepts string as parameter as you can see here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.getfullhtmlfieldname.aspx how can you accomplish to do that with lambda expression?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I just looked at my own code and forgot something. I have the extension method for Generic HtmlHelper `public static string GetFullHtmlFieldName<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
        }` which i use with lambdas

Comment: @archil that would be nice if you could post that by editing your answer. I am really curious about how you do that. thanks.

Comment: @archil ok, you posted it on the comment. that is nice too.

Answer (score 14):

I'm guessing this is only in newer versions of MVC, but you could probably just use:

```
@Html.NameFor(x => x.Name)
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833703(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: +1 Aweswome, I wonder how many people will create an extension that mocks built-in functionality :) Glad I saw this.

Comment: I needed to create my own HtmlHelper extension, and had some trouble even with NameExtensions.NameFor().  But the issue I had was because I implemented my helper and used an expression of type Expression<Func<TModel, object>> rather than using a generic return value, like: Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>.  With "object", it was automatically adding a "Convert" expression, which didn't work properly with NameFor either.  (That said, I'm sure there's still a reason to handle the Convert issue if you really needed to do a cast in the lamdba expression.)