# How do I get access to the model property's name from a child view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

If my model is defined as follows:

```
public class GreaterModel
{
    public IList<LesserModel> MyLesserModelNumber1 {get;set;}
    public IList<LesserModel> MyLesserModelNumber2 {get;set;}
}
public class LesserModel
{
    public string MyString {get;set;}
}
```

and my view like this:

```
@model GreaterModel
<h1>My First Editable List</h1>
@Html.EditorAndAdderFor(m=>m.MyLesserModelNumber1)
<h1>My Second Editable List</h1>
@Html.EditorAndAdderFor(m=>m.MyLesserModelNumber2)
```

EditorAndAdderFor is a custom extension method that works in a similar way than EditorFor. It uses the following partial view to add the markup for editing the list items as well as adding new ones: *(simplified for clarity)*

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
/*There's a lot of markup left out here to do with the editing of items (basically uses @Html.EditorForModel()
)*/

/*Then there is input fields to add new items to the list. */
<input type='text' id='addnew-mystring' />
```

Some JS to handle the new entry:

```
$('#addnew-mystring').focus(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    //now I need to add the new value into the list of existing
    //LesserModel items using the correct form name.
    //I.e. "MyLesserModelNumber1[0].MyString"
})
```

I would like to know which property is calling my editor template from within the editor template view file so that I can give the new entry the correct HTML form name and id for model binding to work. So maybe something like this from the partial view

```
string name = Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName; 
//should contain "MyLesserModelNumber1", 
//but currently is null
```

Comment: It seems odd that the editor template would need to know this.  Sounds like a broken encapsulation.  Perhaps you can convey the information you need by adding a property to `LesserModel` to indicate whatever it is that the editor view needs?  Or wrap `LesserModel` in a custom view model which contains such a property?

Comment: @David - thanks for the advice. I've updated the post so you can see why I'm needing it. I'm trying to simulate the `EditorFor` helper but extending it to have an Adding function (so `EditorAndAdderFor`). For model binding to work I need the property name.

Comment: Conceptually this seems really strange.  The parent model has two lists of items.  Do they get combined into a single list in the UI?  If that's the case then it might make more sense to have a single list in the model (even if it's just a readonly property which concats the two lists).  Is the editor template displaying an *item* or a *list of items*?  There's a huge conceptual difference between the two, and that changes where the "add new" functionality belongs.

Comment: That's very strange design you're using here. Actually i don't think that you will go on with it. Anyway this answer will help you for what you asked about http://stackoverflow.com/a/5514937/105445

Comment: @WahidBitar: Ok maybe it is a strange design in the code, but the concept that I'm trying to achieve is a very simple one. All I want is an `@Html.EditorFor()` call that can edit existing items in the list as well as delete and add new ones. Have you got a better solution for this?

Comment: @WahidBitar: the possible duplicate is not the same concept. In that example the user already has the name of the property (`@Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Name")`) I'm looking for a way to find the "Name" part.

Comment: If you add EditorTemplate for `LesserModel` and used that code in it by passing the name of `MyString` property to it, then you'll get the full path

Comment: Yeah, but the editor template is only called on the existing items in the list, not for adding another entry. The whole purpose here is to extend the EditorFor() on a IEnumerable<T> to be able to add T's

Answer (score 0):

I agree with david's suggestions.
If you need a completely different html for different property use different model and view for each property.
If you need same view and only a slight change depend on the property you should have a property within LesserModel that Distinguishes between the two.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't very clear about the requirements. Please see the updated post. I'm not using different HTML altogether for different properties, I'm only using the property name for model binding purposes.

Comment: ok.why dont you use @Html.TextboxFor(Model->MyString) instead of <input> tag in the LesserModel View? that way it will be mapped automatically

Comment: I am. The post doesn't show what I'm doing in LesserModel's view. It only shows the partial view used by the EditorAndAdderFor extension. There I do not have access to the models in the list, so the model m in `@Html.TextboxFor(m=>m...)` is IEnumerable<object> and not LesserModel

Comment: Well, i guess you have a reason to use object and not LesserModel. But, i think you should rethink of your design, cause you are missing the whole idea of MVC. you shouldn't use any kind of "reflection" in you model view mapping.

Comment: How does the MVC framework do it when you use EditorFor on a list of items then?

Comment: The IEnumerable<object> should be IEnumerable<SpecificModel> for that.
[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1905215.aspx?EditorFor+and+an+IEnumerable+List+) maybe this will help

Comment: Oh sorry, I know how to do it with IEnumerable<T> EditorFor, I'm just wondering how they achieved it without violating these MVC design principles